# How to use java media framework to select video

Tags: java, video, playback, jmf, avi

I am new to JMF, and the sample code allows the user to select a video from file

```
mediaURL = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURL();
```

But i actually need to know how to select a file with the code it self, so I want the application to start and the a video to be played

I tried some thing like `mediaURL="video.mpg"` but it does not work, anyone with experience?

Answer (score 0):

That example uses [JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), you can find how to use it [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). After that, you can play your video like so:

```
Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL );
mediaPlayer.start(); // start playing the media clip
```

I have taken this example from a tutorial [here](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/), which was the result of a simple [Google Search](http://www.google.com.mt/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java%20media%20framework%20tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `mediaURL` is a `URL` object. You could create a [`URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) yourself, or create a [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) (`new File("video.mpg")`)and convert it to a `URL` by calling `File.toURI().toURL()` (because `File.toURL()` is deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

In JMF the mediaURL is a MediaLocator ( a JMF class similar to URL). You can create it by doing
    MediaLocator mediaURL = new MediaLocator("/home/me/video.mpg");
Or its equivalent on whatever OS you are using. You have to give the full path to create the MediaLocator.  Then use the code suggested by @npinti
That code is based on JMF2.0   If you are using 1.0, the API to use is Manager.createPlayer(mediaURL)